# Magento Shipping advanced

Tags: shipping, payment, dhl

Hello Magento Community,
i´m setting up a shop/reseller platform, where sellers first send the package to the shopowner, who will retransfer the item to the buyer. Therefore each party (seller & buyer) have to pay for the shipping costs.

So the seller pays shipping by himself, but needs to define shipping while entering the product to the shop. Because buyer needs to pay the same shipping. So that ther will be no shippingcosts for the shopowner.

I thought about a form/dropdown where the seller can choose from 5 predefines shippign methods, while he inserts an item. Therefore a price will be added to the selling price. I want to use DHL only, but i thing using the DHL Extension woul be too much probably.

How would you solve this ? I´d appeciate some hints and tips very much. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create an attribute with a drop down containing all of the possible shipping choices and make it required.

Assuming they are entering their own items through a role setup in the admin, 
create an extension with an Observer on `catalog_product_save_after` that updates the product price based on their selection.

For example: VendorA logs into the admin to enter a product.  They set a price of $20 and then selects Option1 for shipping that adds $5 in cost.  When they click Save, the product price is set to $25 ($20 + $5). Since the drop down is required there will always be an additional cost added based on their selection.

Alternatively,  the actual cost could also be defined in a required text box attribute that the Observer would use to add to the product price.